# Format Date object without String?

Tags: java

I have a Date Object (Fri Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 1999) and i just want to display 31-12-1999.

And i don't want use String Object for display this information i need to display with a Date Object.

Do you got a solution for this problem ?

Comment: display <=> string (or at least some sort of charsequence)

Comment: Neither String nor Date actually display anything. They're containers for different kinds of data. `System.out.prinln` and the like display things, and `System.out.println` displays a String.

Comment: You're not going to find _any_ way to display anything without a `String` somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = dateFormatter.format(dateInstance);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the Date as text directly to a ByteBuffer which you can write to an IO device. This can be used to speed up logging for example.

The logic for converting dates with timezones is so complex however, I would suggest you use the standard libraries or JodaTime for dates as its not worth trying to write yourself.

For this reason, I write times directly to a ByteBuffer and use SimpleDateFormat to produce a cached String for the date (as it only changes once per day)

If you want to display to a GUI, you will have to use a String because that what the GUI uses.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you need to remove the time information from the Date object? You can do something like this.

```
Date d; // this is your date 
Date dateWithoutTime = new Date(d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay());
```